# PostgreSQL slow nested queries

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to solve a slow query in PostgreSQL. I have a table "**element**" and a table "**relation**"
The table relation enables to put any items of the table "element" in relation with other items of the same table "element".
Another table "**subtype**" describes the type of the element. I list here only the most important columns for clarity.

```
Table: element(id, id_subtype, identification_number)
Table: relation(id, type_source, id_source, type_destination, id_destination)
Table: subtype(id, name, code)
```

I want to list all entries of the table "element" with the following columns:

1. Id, identification_number
2. a concatenated string of all its relations to other elements
3. a concatenated string of all its relations to other elements of the subtype with code = "zone"
4. a concatenated string of all its relations to other elements of the subtype with code = "secteur"

I have this query so far

```
     SELECT 
             e.id, e.name,
             string_agg(distinct(elem_identification_number), ', ') as rel_element_string,
             string_agg(distinct(elem_zone_identification_number), ', ') as rel_zone_element_string,
             string_agg(distinct(elem_sector_identification_number), ', ') as rel_sector_element_string
           FROM(
            
           SELECT e.id,
              CASE
                WHEN elem.id is null THEN null
                ELSE concat(s.name, ' ', elem.identification_number)
                END AS elem_identification_number,  
              CASE
                WHEN s_zone.id is null THEN null
                ELSE elem_zone.identification_number
                END AS elem_zone_identification_number,
              CASE
                WHEN s_sector.id is null THEN null
                ELSE elem_sector.identification_number
                END AS elem_sector_identification_number    
           FROM element e
           LEFT JOIN relation re ON re.id_source = e.id AND re.type_source = 'element' AND re.type_destination = 'element'
           LEFT JOIN element elem ON re.id_destination = elem.id
           LEFT JOIN subtype s ON elem.id_subtype = s.id 
                
           LEFT JOIN relation re_zone ON re_zone.id_source = e.id AND re_zone.type_source = 'element' AND re_zone.type_destination = 'element' AND re_zone.is_deleted = false
           LEFT JOIN element elem_zone ON re_zone.id_destination = elem_zone.id
           LEFT JOIN subtype s_zone ON elem_zone.id_subtype = s_zone.id AND s_zone.code = 'zone' 
            
           LEFT JOIN relation re_sector ON re_sector.id_source = e.id AND re_sector.type_source = 'element' AND re_sector.type_destination = 'element' AND re_sector.is_deleted = false
            LEFT JOIN element elem_sector ON re_sector.id_destination = elem_sector.id
            LEFT JOIN subtype s_sector ON elem_sector.id_subtype = s_sector.id AND s_sector.code = 'secteur'
            WHERE e.is_deleted = false AND e.id_subtype = 18
            
     UNION ALL
                
      /* Same query but with reveresed id_source - id_destination */
  ) as e
   GROUP BY id, e.identification_number, ...
ORDER BY id DESC";
```

The query plan of the full request (with all columns) looks like this with the "explain"

https://explain.depesz.com/s/Lk9h

I also have 2 indexes on table "relation"

```
CREATE INDEX idx_relation
    ON public.relation USING btree
    (id_chantier ASC NULLS LAST, type_source COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, id_source ASC NULLS LAST)

CREATE INDEX idx_relation_dest
    ON public.relation USING btree
    (id_chantier ASC NULLS LAST, type_destination COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, id_destination ASC NULLS LAST)
```

Any idea how I can improve the query?
Thank you!

Comment: You have to post the complete `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, properly indented.

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Thanks, I just added the link to the explain as requested.

Comment: As both condition in WHERE clause is left table columns so you can add where clause condition at ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have a combinatorial explosion here.  For example, if each of your string_aggs produces a list of a 100 things for each e, you first have a dataset of 100^3, or a million things, per e before the distinct compacts it back down again.

The way to avoid that is to not write one 10-way join, but rather write 3 correlated subqueries where each subquery has a 3-way join plus a reference to the outer table.  Something like:

```
select e.*,
    (select string_agg(...) from relation, element, subtype ...) rel_element_string,
    (select string_agg(...) from relation, element, subtype ...) rel_zone_element_string,
    (select string_agg(...) from relation, element, subtype ...) rel_sector_element_string
from elements e
WHERE e.is_deleted = false AND e.id_subtype = 18
```